# How to convert Hex into Signed Integer using python3

Tags: python-3.x, unsigned, signed

what is the simplest way to print the result as follows using pyhton3

1. I have a Hex string `s="FFFC"`
2. In python if using this command line: `print(int(s,16))`
3. The result I'm expecting is -4 (which is in signed format). But this is not the case, It displays the Unsigned format which the result is 65,532.
4. How can I convert this the easiest way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways, but you could just do the math explicitly (assuming `s` has no more than 4 characters, otherwise use `s[-4:]`):

```
i = int(s, 16)
if i >= 0x8000:
    i -= 0x10000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bytes.fromhex` and `int.from_bytes` class methods.

```
s = bytes.fromhex('FFFC')
i = int.from_bytes(s, 'big', signed=True)
print(i)
```

Pretty self-explanatory, the only thing that might need clarification is the `'big'` argument, but that just means that the byte array `s` has the most significant byte first.

Comment: Bad language design that fromhex does not accept hex(n).